# Redirection 301 discarding a specific parameter in a group of dynamic parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

First of all I wanted to apologize for my English.

I have to do a series of 301 redirects on a site where all the urls are going to be changed.

An example is the following

I have a url that can have different parameters:

**Example 1**
www.domain.com/post/?id=specificID&utm_source=val1&utm_campaign=val2&utm_medium=val3

**Example 2**
www.domain.com/post/?utm_medium=val3&utm_campaign=val2&utm_source=val1&id=post_slug

**Example 3**
www.domain.com/post/?id=specificID&utm_source=val1&utm_campaign=val2

In all the examples I need to redirect to another url keeping only the 'utm' parameters

The most important thing for this redirection is:
- Only the parameters 'id' and 'utm_source' are safe in the original url.
- The parameter 'id' does not have to be in the destination url.

The destination url in each example should be this:

**Example 1**
www.domain.com/en/specificID/?utm_source=val1&utm_campaign=val2&utm_medium=val3

**Example 2**
www.domain.com/en/specificID/?utm_campaign=val2&utm_source=val1&id=post_slug

**Example 3**
www.domain.com/en/specificID/?utm_source=val1&utm_campaign=val2

The rewrite rule that I have is this:

```
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI} /post
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} id=lorem-ipsum
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} utm_source
RewriteRule ^ /en/lorem-ipsum [R=301,L,QSA]
```

The problem I have with this configuration is that the id parameter reaches me at the destination url always and is mandatory that is not so.

With this rule the destination url are:

**Example 1**
www.domain.com/en/specificID/?id=specificID&utm_source=val1&utm_campaign=val2&utm_medium=val3

**Example 2**
www.domain.com/en/specificID/?utm_medium=val3&utm_campaign=val2&utm_source=val1&id=post_slug

**Example 3**
www.domain.com/en/specificID/?id=specificID&utm_source=val1&utm_campaign=val2

I know this happens to me by the QSA flag, but honestly, I can not think of another way to do it.

In short, the problem is that I never know how many utm parameters will arrive at the origin URL or the order in which they arrive, but I have to keep them all in the destination url and discarding only the id parameter.

Thank you very much in advance.